# How to center ticks labels in Chartjs?

Tags: chart.js, vuejs3, vue-chartjs

I want to align my labels (sunday,monday ect....) center in the grey background, how can I do that in chartJS ?

[image: Screenshot here]

I would need something like padding top but I cant see it in documentation. My code:

```
scales: {
        x: {
          backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
          grid: {
            display: false,
          },
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 1,
            font: {
              weight: 700,
            },
            color: '#404040',
          },
          offset: true,
        },
        y: {
          backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
          grid: {
            display: false,
          },
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 1,
            font: {
              weight: 700,
            },
            color: '#343b7e',
          },
          offset: true,
        },
      },
```